# Visualforce Component Saving data

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

below is my code, I have created an VF Component/VFP/Controller

My question is: How can I save the value of the `<apex:inputField` in the VF Component

```
<apex:component>

  <apex:attribute name="fname" description="fn" type="myCustomObject__c" required="true" /> 
  <apex:attribute name="mname" description="mn" type="myCustomObject__c" required="true" /> 
  <apex:attribute name="lname" description="ln" type="myCustomObject__c" required="true" /> 

    <!-- more fields -->
    <apex:inputText value="{!fname.f_name__c}" id="fname"> </apex:inputText>
    <apex:inputText value="{!mname.m_name__c}" id="mname"> </apex:inputText>
    <apex:inputText value="{!lname.l_name__c}" id="lname"> </apex:inputText>

</apex:component>
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="NameInputTextPageController" >

  <apex:form>

  <c:NameInputTextComponent id="vfcom" 
      fname="{!firstname}" mname="{!middlename}" lname="{!lastname}"
  />

    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveme}" value="Save Data" />

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF Page Controller:

```
public with sharing class NameInputTextPageController {
    public NameInputTextPageController() {}

    public PageReference saveme() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is doesn't have the properties defined you are trying to reference...

Comment: correct! that's the part i'm trying to know how to handle it

Comment: `saveMe` isn't doing any DML

Comment: @crop1645:  i have just created action and off course needs to address how to grab the user entry data and save it and yes eventually it will be doing DML operation. sorry for the confusion

Comment: so firstName, middleName, and lastName are three instances of `myCustomObject__c` ? A separate object for each portion of someone's name?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your last question but `First,Middle,Last name` are of same myCustomObject__c instance

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

- <s>Add `allowDml="true"` to your `<apex:component>` tag.</s>
- You only need to pass one instance of your record, not three.
- <s>You can pass an `ApexPage.Action` and invoke that from your component.</s>

Your markup could probably be simplified to something like:

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        <c:nameInputs record="MyObject__c" />
    <apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Then your component:

```
<apex:component allowDml="true">
    <apex:attribute name="record" type="MyObject__c" required="true"
        description="SObject record to edit" />\

    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.f_name__c}" id="fname" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.m_name__c}" id="mname" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.l_name__c}" id="lname" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: 1+ make sense how you simplified the page but confused where does the saving take place? i mean controller?

Comment: @AbuHamzah Just add it to a `commandButton` as you would with the `save` action normally. Updated my markup to demonstrate.

Comment: but if you look at my markup the `save button` is on the VF page not on the VF component.

Comment: @AbuHamzah Just use the save action on your page instead then. This structure will bind the values back.

Comment: I'm not getting the value so I have `allowDml="true` in the component and in the VF page I have  `public PageReference save() {  system.debug(MyObject__c.f_name__c)  }`  i get empty value in the debug

Comment: @AbuHamzah Why do you even need an extension at all? Just use the `StandardController`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36481/discussion-between-abu-hamzah-and-adrian-larson).